# Python typehint subset(partial) of an TypedDict

Tags: python, type-hinting, partial, python-typing, typeddict

In typescript we have [Partial type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype), so we can do this:

```js
interface Foo {
    x:number
    y:number
}

const foo:Partial<Foo> = {x: 1}
```

(With this we can make all properties of an interface optional)

In Python, we could do this with a `total=False`, like this:

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict


class Foo(TypedDict, total=False):
    x:int
    y:int

foo:Foo = {'x':1}
```

But this approach is not too good, because this implies that all `Foo` must have all properties as possible None, and we need to do a lot of typecasting. Is there, in python, a way to declare a TypedDict and then make some implementation of it a subset of this type, like this:

```
from typing_extensions import TypedDict


class Foo(TypedDict):
    x: int
    y: int


foo:Partial[Foo] = {'x': 1}
```

Comment: For those of us not intimately familiar with TypeScript, can you clarify what behaviour you expect? The linked docs say that is ``Partial<Type>`` is a type with "all properties of ``Type`` set to optional". That seems to match "that all ``Foo`` must have all properties as possible None". Do you want to have *two* versions of ``Foo``, one with all properties non-optional and one with all properties optional?

Comment: I wrote a commend about Partial in my last Edit.
But the idea is that typescript `Partial` allows us to take an interface whose properties is all required and turn all those properties into optional so that we can make implementations of this interface a subset of it but keep the interface property's required. `total=True` doesn't allow that, because we need to change the `TypedDict` directly.

Comment: I think the answer is that this probably isn't really possible in python currently. But, you could always write a PEP for it, if you feel it's something the language is currently lacking.

Comment: Why not defining a second type `PartialType` which is just equal to `Partial<Type>`?

Comment: Part of the problem here is that the static type is supposed to prescribe what value can be assigned to `foo`, rather than the type inferring the desired structure *from* an arbitrary value. Python's type system is, I think, too different from the one used by TypeScript to support such an operation.

Comment: Instead of trying to fit the mold exactly from the structure in Typescript, could you instead post the relevant Python code which is awkward to write because of this issue? I think you might be able to use a different pattern to alleviate the issues you find due to the lack of this pattern. Otherwise this feels more like an x y problem.

Comment: I have a generic class with a `TypedDict` type argument, and I'm essentially implementing a `dict.update`, which allows for changing only parts of the `TypedDict`. Without some kind of `Partial` type decorator, every call to the `dict.update` analog is marked incorrect unless its dict arg defines _all_ the `TypedDict` fields — which is semantically incorrect, as defining those fields changes the functionality (and can result in race conditions, when the underlying dict has changed in between access and update).

Comment: I have created a topic on python.org regarding this question: https://discuss.python.org/t/introduce-partial-for-typeddict/45176

Answer (score 4):

From Python3.11, we have `typing.NotRequired`.
The Doc is [Here](https://docs.python.org/3.11/library/typing.html#typing.NotRequired), and PEP is [Here](https://peps.python.org/pep-0655/).

This marks variable as *potentially-missing*.

Like

```python
from typing import TypedDict, NotRequired

class Movie(TypedDict):
    title: str
    year: NotRequired[int]
```

Comment: While this goes in the right direction, to have the equivalent to TS, we would need something like `Partial[Movie]` to return a version of movie where every property is `NotRequired`.